# Retrieve Activities of an entity in CRM 2011 using CRM sdk rest

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have used SDK Rest javascript that came with CRM SDK kit to retrieve attributes (fields) of crm entities, manipulate the same.

For example I use this SDK rest javascript as follows in my web resource;

```js
var options = "$select=FullName,SystemUserId&$filter=(IsDisabled eq false) and (AccessMode/Value ne 3)";
SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords("SystemUser", options, retrieveUsersCallBack, function (error) { alert(error.message); }, UserRetrieveComplete);
```

I would like to know if there is a way to retrieve "notes and activities" mainly emails regarding a particular entity, so that i can move the same to another entity based on certain condition.

Thank you all

Sorry I just landed on the answer which is as follows

```js
 var options = "$select=Lead_Emails&$expand=Lead_Emails&$filter=LeadId eq guid"+"'"+idOfCurrentLead+"'";
```

But I would like to know how do i move these emails to another entity (opportunity) record on qualify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var options = "$select=Lead_Emails&$expand=Lead_Emails&$filter=LeadId eq guid"+"'"+idOfCurrentLead+"'";
```

Sorry Guys I just figured out the answer.